# Sending an array of files loaded from local machine as raw data to my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http

i have an array of files that i want to send as request (using request) to my server

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");

var img = [];
img.push(fs.readFileSync("./test_images/0000.png", "binary"));
img.push(fs.readFileSync("./test_images/0001.png", "binary"));
img.push(fs.readFileSync("./test_images/0002.png", "binary"));
img.push(fs.readFileSync("./test_images/0003.png", "binary"));

function analyze_raw(images)
{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
    var options = 
        {
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/face",
        method: "GET",
        //headers: //not working
        //  {
        //  Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"
        //  },
        body: images
        };

    request(options, function(err, response)
        {
        if(err)
            {
            return resolve(err);
            }
        else
            {
            return resolve(response.body);
            }
        });

    });
}
analyze_raw(img);
```

my server should take the files and send various requests to Microsoft vision services, put them together and send the result back.
The version that sends pictures as web urls works, but i have to make it work with raw files as well, and i've no idea if i'm sending the files wrongly to my server, or if what i'm sending is just not what vision api are expecting.

Each request to Microsoft vision should be of type "application/octet-stream".
Each request to my server should contain a list of raw images, then it takes care of making individual requests.

The problem is i've no idea where is my error here, nor how to do it properly.

---

Here is the code of my server that calls Microsoft services for individual images (which works for urls when json argument is true)

```
function microsoft_request(req_url, req_content, method, req_key, json = true)
{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
    var microsoft_request_options = 
        {
        "url": keys.base_url + req_url,
        "method": method,
        "body": req_content,
        "headers": 
            {
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": req_key
            }
        };

    if(json) { microsoft_request_options.json = true; }
    else { microsoft_request_options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"; }

    //send request
    request(microsoft_request_options, function(err, response)
        {
        if(err)
            {
            return reject({error: {statusCode: 500, message: err}});
            }
        else if(response.statusCode != 200)
            {
            return reject({error: {statusCode: response.statusCode, message: response.body}});
            }
        else
            {
            return resolve({content: response.body});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

[Here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) is the documentation for the API i'm trying to use.
The error i get from Microsoft vision when calling my own service with a list of raw files is the following (identical for each image):

```
{
"error":
    {
    "code": "InvalidImage",
    "message": "Decoding error, image format unsupported."
    }
}
```

The images are jpg or png, both supported according to the documentation. That leads me to believe something weird happens and javascript's non existent strong or static typing is driving me crazy.

Comment: You will need to either use a POST or a PUT request. GET requests may have a body but it's recommended for servers to ignore it.

Comment: well my server doesn't ignore it, and changing the method doesn't change the results @JulianF.Weinert

Comment: Why don't you convert that raw info into jpegs? I think it could be more easly achievable.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just dealt with something similar. Request doesn't seem to document it super well,  but most likely the best solution is to take the files and upload using multipart.

What you were doing was trying to take binary data and GET with a body. That's just not going to work. You want to

- Use POST or PUT
- Send using `multipart/form-data`

  ```
  var fs = require("fs");
  var request = require("request");
  var img = [];
  img.push(fs.createReadStream("./test_images/0000.png"));
  img.push(fs.createReadStream("./test_images/0001.png"));
  img.push(fs.createReadStream("./test_images/0002.png"));
  img.push(fs.createReadStream("./test_images/0003.png"));

  function analyze_raw(images) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var options = {
              url: "http://localhost:3000/api/face",
              method: "POST", // or PUT
              formData: {
                  images // ES6 shorthand
              }
          };
          request(options, function(err, response) {
              if(err) {
                  return resolve(err);
              } else {
                  return resolve(response.body);
              }
          });
      });
  }
  ```

On your server you would want to handle the multipart upload with a library like multer or formidable.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you pointed says:

Supported image formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP.
Image file size must be less than 4MB.
Image dimensions must be at least 50 x 50.

The way you send them is the whole body needs to be it's binary output and then specify Content-Type like, e.g.: PNG (multipart/form-data or application/octet-stream).

Comment: that's what i'm doing (or trying to). My server takes individual images from the array and sends the request to vision with a single image raw data using application/octet-stream.
The first block of code in my post is the request i send to my server, not to microsoft

Comment: Can you confirm req_content has only binary data as content?